# Updating a JS object based upon element ID

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My goal is to update part of a nested JS object, based upon user specified details. My problem is that i'm struggling to write a loop that can correctly identify the part of the nested obj that the updates were taken from and therefor making it impossible to replace them currently.

I have the following obj - http://pastebin.com/ZnZbh8dz

If we take the obj with an ID of 4, for example. That contains another nested object of `data`, which contains

`"title":"BEFORE",
"statusGroup":"moose",
"stockResponse":"BEFORE"`

I want to replace that data with the data inside of another object, that other object will have the structure of - http://pastebin.com/zGVuLJnn

But i'm struggling to loop through the large object, identify where the `id` matches the `id` of the updated object, and then replace it within the large object.

If my explanation doesn't make sense then feel free to ask me to clarify further. The task itself should be quite simple, i'd assumed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using a function I found online and modifying it for my needs

```
function findAndReplace(object, value, replacevalue, field, objId) {

    for (var x in object) {
        if (typeof object[x] == 'object') {
            findAndReplace(object[x], value, replacevalue, field, objId);
        }
    }

    if (object[x] == value) {
        object[field] = replacevalue;
    }
}
```